# how to deploy flask apps to ubuntu

Tags: python, apache, ubuntu, deployment, flask

I know a document on digitalocean exists for this question but for some reason it doesn't really work.

**Ubuntu**:14.04
**HTTP Server**: apache2
**Module**:wsgi

#### Status

Followed the whole tutorial and edited the files accordingly to match with my flask project, the thing is that even though everything is deployed according to the documentation the domain nor the server ip show any response like they have too.

#### Code

**filename**:numiCloud.wsgi

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/numiCloud/")

from numiCloud import app as application
application.secret_key = 'Add your secret key'
```

**filename**:/var/www/numiCloud/numiCloud/__init__.py

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def root():
    return "Deployed!"

if __name__=="__main__':
    app.run()
```

**filename**:/etc/apache2/sites-available/numiCloud.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName 183.83.199.118

    WSGIDaemonProcess numiCloud user=devx136 threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/numiCloud/numicloud.wsgi

    <Directory /var/www/numiCloud/>
        WSGIProcessGroup numiCloud
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**filename**:/var/log/apache2/error.log
[**link**](https://bpaste.net/show/637d3a3cd5d7)

the wsgi module is enabled and the virtual host of the apache is also enabled but as i still don't see the text that i wan't it to return. The site shows a 404 not found error no matter what.

update : well no one seems to know the solution..

Comment: what is your flask default port, you can't serve more than 1 on single port.

Comment: the default port is 5000 and I can assure that nothing else is on that port and as this is being deployed to an http server like apache i don't think it uses it's port.

Comment: You should get rid of `if __name__ == "__main__": app.run()` because it will create a local wsgi server. Check this doc out: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/mod_wsgi/

Comment: @Leandro the docs say to either use the if block or totally move it to another file.

Comment: Is there something on the Apache log files related to this site. Also, it could be helpful if you posted the Apache site file, it might be misconfigured.

Comment: @martinarroyo added the config

Comment: I have same situation like you - flask deploy guide is written here and there but we can't get it run. Wonder why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just hoping no one else landed on this problem but the only thing I did was change the web server to nginx and used gunicorn instead to configure the python script execution.

For people who were able to get it working on apache and if I've done something wrong here in the config please report.

Comment: Your original problem with Apache was possibly because if using name based virtual hosts, then ServerName should not be an IP address to start with. But then, there is a lack of information, such as whether you even enabled the site, it isn't enough just to stick it in site-available.

Comment: It says that i followed the DO post about this setup and everything including the mod and site was enabled. I can't just make a huge blog post over here.

Comment: If DO says to set ServerName to an IP address then they are giving wrong advice. That will not work if there are multiple VirtualHost's defined on the system. The only chance it would work is if there was only one VirtualHost and Apache in not knowing what to do, because ServerName wouldn't match, would fall back to using the first VirtualHost.

Comment: I found here one thing the author shares same case with us http://alex.nisnevich.com/blog/2014/10/01/setting_up_flask_on_ec2.html

Comment: May try `sudo apachectl restart`

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton could you please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58718569/cannot-load-pytorch-model-in-a-flask-app-runned-on-ubuntu-machine-with-apache-we